# 70's short story about a man who gets revelations about winning lottery numbers

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

This is a short story I read when I was a teenager - it must have been in the 70's - and I don't remember too much.

There was a man, who kept having a dream in which he talked to a humanoid alien - he was asked something to the effect of 'What am I', and he got it wrong several times, until he struck on something like '... from the Mother Planet' or similar. After that he was given series of numbers every time, which turned out to be the winning combinations in a major lottery (I think); in the end he was arrested on suspicion of somehow cheating.

It is my impression that the story wasn't exactly new at the time - I read it as a story in a paperback.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**"Manden fra Moderkloden"**

If by chance you might have read it in Danish, this sounds quite a lot like Arne Hartmann's short story "Manden fra Moderkloden" (literally "The Man from the Mother Planet"). It was published in the fanzine *Proxima* in October 1977, and I don't think it was ever reprinted, nor translated into English, though I could be mistaken.

I remember the bit about the lottery numbers (although I remember it as pools betting on soccer games), and the "Mother Planet" bit is exactly like what you remember.

[image: magazine cover, mostly yellow, reading "Proxima Dansk Science Fiction Tidsskrift", hand-drawn black planet-like shape]

Comment: Yep, that's the one - it must have been reprinted at least once, since I don't remember ever seeing Proxima before. It was a slightly Hippyish story; very Zeitgeist...

Comment: There aren't all that many reprint anthologies of old Danish SF. I thought it might be in "De smukke drømmes palads", but it isn't in the content list. However, Hartmann has several short story collections; maybe it was reprinted in one of them. https://www.saxo.com/dk/forfatter/arne-hartmann_4345329?page=1